# localStorage overwrites my previous table data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm using onClick function to return array data to store on localStorage to display rows in a table.
But, whenever onClick button is triggered it overwrites the previous data table. Any help would be appreciated!

JavaScript:

```
function storeData(arr){
    
    localStorage.setItem("empObj",JSON.stringify(arr));
}

function displayData(){

    let empJson = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("empObj"));

    var tableContent =""
    var startTable = "<table border=1 width=200 align=center><tr><th>Item</th><th>Price</th></tr>"
    tableContent = "<tr><td>"+empJson[0]+"</td><td>"+empJson[1]+"</td></tr>"
    var endTable = "</table>"
    tableContent = startTable+tableContent+endTable
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=tableContent;    
}
```

HTML:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary"
    onClick="return storeData(['itemNumber1','$1,000'])">Add</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary"
    onClick="return storeData(['itemNumber2','$900'])">Add</button>
```

To display the table, I'm using onload function

```
window.onload = function() {
                   displayData();
                }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9KcE.jpg

Comment: Hi Jason, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide more information as to what data (and the data structure) you're storing in the localStorage key `empObj`?

Comment: Your code is just adding one element to `localStorage` and displaying the same item again and again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the proper implementation should be like this:

```
function storeData(arr){
    // add 1 row instead of overwriting the whole array.
    // to do so, it must read the previous data from storage first
    const prevArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("empObj")) || [];
    // concatenate with previous data
    localStorage.setItem("empObj",JSON.stringify([...prevArr, arr]));
}

function displayData(empObj){
    let empJson = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("empObj"));

    var tableContent =""
    var startTable = "<table border=1 width=200 align=center><tr><th>Item</th><th>Price</th></tr>"
    tableContent = "<tr><td>"+empJson[0]+"</td><td>"+empJson[1]+"</td></tr>"
    var endTable = "</table>"
    tableContent = startTable+tableContent+endTable
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=tableContent;    
}

// html
<!-- return is unncessary in this case -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary"
  onClick="() => storeData(['itemNumber1','$1,000'])">Add</button>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  displayData();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at displayData (savedcart.js:14)" It's referring to line "tableContent = "<tr><td>"+empJson[0]"

Comment: I forgot to add null coalescing on that part:

`let empJson = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("empObj")) || [];`

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage.setItem` will always set the localStorage data against a particular key. Which means it overwrites previous data. If you want to keep the previous data aswell, you have to take the data from `localStorage` and append the new data with the existing one and update the localStorage with new data. Here is a working sample in your case.

```js
function storeData(arr) {
    const previousData = localStorage.getItem("empObj");
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(previousData) || [];
    jsonData.push(arr);
    localStorage.setItem("empObj", JSON.stringify(jsonData));
}

function displayData(empObj) {
    let empJson = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("empObj")) || [];
    var tableContent = ""
    var startTable = "<table border=1 width=200 align=center><tr><th>Item</th><th>Price</th></tr>"
    empJson.forEach((node) => {
        tableContent += "<tr><td>" + node[0] + "</td><td>" + node[1] + "</td></tr>"
    })
    var endTable = "</table>"
    tableContent = startTable + tableContent + endTable
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = tableContent;
}

window.onload = function () {
    displayData();
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary"
    onClick="return storeData(['itemNumber1','$1,000'])">Add</butto
```